# Lubuntu - Install Docky

Tags: lubuntu, docky

I switched from Ubuntu to Lubuntu, and was wondering if installing Docky would be the same in terminal commands. These are the commands:

- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:docky-core/ppa`
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install docky`

Thanks!

Comment: Yes it will the same but almost you don't need to add repository it's added by default.
possible error of `Docky Compositing` and here a solution to problem http://www.unixmen.com/quick-tip-fix-docky-compositing-error-lubuntu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there should be no need for any difference in the commands you use as long as the Docky PPA you are using have packages which support your version, but you'll soon find out if that's not the case (when you run the install command it will just tell you that no packages are found for that version). If you do get problems from the PPA though just installing the normal `docky` package from the standard repositories should suffice.